# TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a play surface out of rects in pygame.  I'm not sure what the problem is exactly but I believe it has something to do with the actual iteration of the list when creating the rects.  Sorry, noob here. :)

```
import pygame

w = 800
h = 600
board_pos = 0, 0
tile = 27
playfield = 0

class Board(object):
    def __init__(self, surface, pos, tile_size):
        self.surface = surface
        self.x, self.y = pos
        self.tsize = tile_size
        self.color = 50, 50, 50

        playfield = [list(None for i in xrange(22)) for i in xrange(10)]  

    def draw(self):
        for i in xrange(10):
            for j in xrange(22):
                playfield[i][j] = pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.color,
                                                  (self.x + (i * self.tsize),
                                                   self.y + (j * self.tsize),
                                                   self.tsize, self.tsize))

pygame.display.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))

board = Board(screen, board_pos, tile)
board.draw()

while __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.display.flip()
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My
Documents\Dropbox\Programming\DeathTris
\test2.py", line 30, in <module>
    board.draw()
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My
Documents\Dropbox\Programming\DeathTris
\test2.py", line 24, in draw
    self.tsize, self.tsize))
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your line `playfield = [list(None for i in xrange(22)) for i in xrange(10)]` creates a local variable inside the `__init__` function.  That variable disappears after the `__init__` function returns.  Later in `draw` when you do `playfield[i][j]`, you are accessing the global value of `playfield`, which is still 0 (since you initialized it to 0 at the beginning).

If you want to overwrite the global playfield from inside your `__init__`, you need to do `global playfield` before you assign to it.  (But. . . why are you using a global variable for this anyway?)

Comment: It should definitely be `self.playfield`.

Comment: Thank you guys so much!  I had been plugging away at this for hours.

Comment: [... for i ... for i...] Doesn't this need two different vars?

Comment: @thefritobandit please make sure to accept the answer (click the checkmark below the arrows) so that we know this question has been answered. You also get +2 rep for accepting :)