# TypeError 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, django

I've got a Django model Partner defined as follows:

```
class Partner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    identity = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    phone = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.identity

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
        return reverse('partner', kwargs={'partner_url': self.identity})
```

It has been registered in admin.py as follows:

```
admin.site.register(Partner)
```

However, in the admin console when I try to add data, it gives me the following error:

```
TypeError at /admin/Project/partner/add/
'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I tried other solutions like the ones present here:

[TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908818/typeerror-int-object-has-no-attribute-getitem)

and

[float object has no attribute __getitem__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091109/float-object-has-no-attribute-getitem?rq=1)

But neither fixed my problem or I'm going about it wrong. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TypeError 'x' object has no attribute '\_\_getitem\_\_'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074331/typeerror-x-object-has-no-attribute-getitem)

Comment: The one I've referred to as duplicate is exactly what's your problem is about.

Comment: @alecxe That one is different as it is spanning a relationship with unicode. This is an integer issue.

Comment: Just try to replace `return self.identity` with `return unicode(self.identity)` and see if the error remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `__unicode__` on an `IntegerField`, which won't work. You'll need to convert to a string.

Try:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.identity)
```